# SharePoint CSOM Powershell - Get Count of files in each folder in Library

Tags: file, powershell, count, sharepoint-2013, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I have a document library which contains many folders.
I want to get count of items within each folder in this library.

I would like to understand if this can be achieved using CSOM Powershell.

Is there any OOTB way?

Answer (score 0):

Just as a forewarning, I am not sure CSOM Powershell has the same cmdlets as traditional powershell. Let me know if they do and I'll get rid of this post. If not, this should work:

Assuming a structure where you have `[library]` containing `[folders]` containing all the files you want to count.

```
foreach($folder in (Get-ChildItem $[library])){  
    $filecount = 0
    Get-ChildItem $folder -recurse |
    %{$filecount += 1}
    #do whatever you want with $filecount here.
}
```

You could use a dictionary or another data structure to keep count of what folders have how many items, outside the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The number of files in folder could be retrieved via [`ItemChildCount` field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid.itemchildcount.aspx), here is an example that demonstrates how to get the files number per folder:

```
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)  
$ctx.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password, $domain)
$list = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents")

$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$query.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
<ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name='FileRef' />
    <FieldRef Name='ItemChildCount' />
</ViewFields>
<Query>
    <Where>
       <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name='FSObjType' />
         <Value Type='Integer'>1</Value>
       </Eq>
   </Where>
</Query>
</View>"

$items = $list.GetItems($query)
$ctx.Load($items) 
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()


$items.GetEnumerator() | % {

   Write-Host $_["FileRef"] , ":" , $_["ItemChildCount"]
}

$ctx.Dispose()
```